# For mixed effects model with multiple random intercepts, are bayesian approaches (with MCMC) more robust than frequentist?

Tags: bayesian, lme4-nlme, frequentist, brms

I stumbled upon this particular webpage from  [UCLA](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/) containing the following text:

> [...]
> Inference from GLMMs is complicated. Except for cases where there are many observations at each level (particularly the highest), assuming that (frac{Estimate}{SE}) is normally distributed may not be accurate. A variety of alternatives have been suggested including Monte Carlo simulation, Bayesian estimation, and bootstrapping.

Without bootstrapping then, are frequentist methods (e.g., via glmer) less robust than bayesian MCMC?

Comment: MCMC is a simulation method. As such it is not endowed with statistical properties such as robustness or asymptotic normality. Please rephrase your question.